# Can you disable SQL query datasets in Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have recently upgraded from Reporting Services 2005 to 2008 R2. In the 2005 version of Report Builder (1.0), you could only create reports from a published model. In the 2008 version (3.0) you can create reports from a model or from a SQL query.

We'd like to restrict users from being able to create reports from a SQL query and require them to use a model instead as we don't want them to be able to query the database directly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the users from having select access to the database itself. Use a separate account for the model.

The other part of this is a people problem, where you will have to explain to users what they need to do and why.

Comment: We're already planning on reworking our sql security model, so we'll address this as you suggested. Thanks!